# Java Event listening compared to AS3

Tags: java, android, actionscript-3, events, event-handling

ok first of all sorry if its a stupid question, but I have ADHD and my head is going to explode after reading a lot of useless details, I just want a small, clear example and I'll predict the rest!

Basically I am playing with the Android SDK, and thought its similar to Adobe Flex, and everything went smooth until I tried listening to a Button click.

in AS3:

```
private function onAddedToStage(event:Event):void
{
    myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,handleClick);
}

private function handleClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("You clicked: " + event.currentTarget.name);
}
```

what I've done so far with trial and error:

```
private Button _okButton;
private EditText _name;
private View _view;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Log.d("trace", "it works!");

    _view = getCurrentFocus();
    _name = (EditText) _view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    _okButton = (Button) _view.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    _name.setText("Yupee I found it!");

    OnClickListener l = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("trace", "Button clicked");
        }
    };

    _okButton.setOnClickListener(l);
}
```

The code above crashes the application

Thanks in advance.

Comment: look at the logcat and report your stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace _view by this.

Comment: wow! it worked!
strangely if I comment the listening part it works (I can access the EditText) ... well whatever at least I can move forward.
Thanks a ton.

Comment: It is important that is your activity itself that holds its widgets. I never saw getFocusView before. A good reference to start android development is anddev book.

Comment: onCreate is a method of Activity which is likely what you are extending on this class. I generally don't even preface the findViewById with a context (or view etc) in an activity. But as Snicolas mentioned, replace the _view and you are golden.